# Publisher clarification for Event Aggregator design pattern

Tags: .net, design-patterns, eventaggregator

I would like to clarify the role of the "publisher" in the Event Aggregator design pattern.

My current solution handles .NET data events, such as XmlNode events occuring in a XmlDocument.

Question:
In the Event Aggregator design pattern, what is considered the publishers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Event Aggregator pattern, you have you types of publishers:

1. Source of events which the aggregator is an observer/subscriber to,
2. The aggregator itself, which has it's own subscribers

So your data sources are publishers.

take a look to this short article by Martin Fowler:

http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html